# How to run Java program on more than one node?

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, parallel-processing, boyer-moore

I want to implement the Boyer-Moore string matching algorithm but I want to implement that algorithm using a parallel approach. I want to show the difference in the execution time when the algorithm is executed in parallel and that when in sequential.

For this I'm thinking of running my code on cluster of nodes. At this moment I'm planning to use AWS(Amazon Web Services) - EMR(Elastic Map Reduce) using the Hadoop, but the problem is I'm finding AWS very hard to use.

Are there any other services like AWS which can help me in running my Java code in parallel on more than one cluster? I'm open to any suggestions regarding how to run my code in parallel.

Comment: Have you parallelised your code? Hadoop won't allow you to simply execute a parallelised Java job on multiple nodes - you'd need to use something like MapReduce or Spark to write your algorithm.

Comment: @BenWatson I'm new in the area of parallel programming, can you recommend me any tutorials?

Comment: @BenWatson I have made some progress and now this is where I have stucked myself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617193/how-to-save-and-run-a-java-file-in-putty Can you help me in resolving this?